# LINQ GroupBy with Sum

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get a client's most popular products (ordered the most by quantity) using a LINQ query. I have the right results when I run this SQL query:

```
SELECT TOP(15) i.ProductId, p.Description, Sum(i.Quantity) As QuantityOrdered
FROM Orders o 
INNER JOIN OrderItems i ON o.Id = i.OrderId
INNER JOIN Products p ON i.ProductId = p.Id 
WHERE o.ClientId = 19
GROUP BY ProductId, Description
ORDER BY QuantityOrdered DESC
```

It gives me the right results:

[image]

I'm trying to duplicate these results using LINQ and here is what I have so far:

```
var query = _context.Set<OrderItem>()
            .Where(oi => oi.Order.ClientId == input.ClientId)
            .GroupBy(oi => oi.ProductId)
            .Select(group => group.Sum(item => item.Quantity))
            .Take(15);
```

All I get here is a list of Sums, but I don't know how to include the product id and description. Secondly how do I include an OrderBy so that the highest sum appears first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to project the `ProductId` and `Description` as well as the `Sum()` in the `Select` projection:

```
var query = _context.Set<OrderItem>()
    .Where(oi => oi.Order.ClientId == input.ClientId)
    .GroupBy(oi => oi.ProductId)
    .Select(group => 
        new { 
            ProductId = group.Key, 
            Description = group.First().Description, 
            Sum = group.Sum(item => item.Quantity)
            })
    .OrderByDescending(i => i.Sum)
    .Take(15);
```

The group key is the `ProductId` so we can use this to project the key. The `Description` we need to get from the first item in the group.

Comment: You forgot the OrderBy

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

```
var query = _context.Set<OrderItem>()
        .Where(oi => oi.Order.ClientId == input.ClientId)
        .GroupBy(oi => oi.ProductId)
        .OrderByDescending(group => group.Sum(item => item.Quantity))
        .Take(15);
```

Also I don't understand why are you grouping them? If you have one record for each product all you need to do is this:

```
var query = _context.Set<OrderItem>()
        .Where(oi => oi.Order.ClientId == input.ClientId)
        .OrderByDescending(product => product.Quantity)
        .Take(15);
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the equivalent to the SQL he has shown expressed with LINQ